# Is there any way to export total in summary row in a plain file?

Tags: java, datatable, primefaces, export

I am using primefaces 8.0 to show a data table with partial results. I mean, a total of quantities by day. In the view it works, but when i try to export it, it doesn't show any total. I've been searching on the internet and they talk about to use primefaces extensions but it doesn't work for me either.

This my datatable

```
<p:dataTable id="Opcion1" value="#{llamadaBean.lista1}" var="lista1" rows="50"
                         paginator="true"
                         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                         currentPageReportTemplate="{startRecord}-{endRecord} of {totalRecords} records"
                         sortBy="#{lista1.fecha}">
                <p:column headerText="FECHA">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{lista1.fecha}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="HORA">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{lista1.hora}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="TRANSACCIONES">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{lista1.numTransacciones}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:summaryRow>
                    <p:column colspan="2" style="text-align:right">
                        <h:outputText value="Total:" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{lista1.totalTransacciones}">                                        
                        </h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
                </p:summaryRow>
            </p:dataTable>
```

[image: And this is what it shows]

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to export a Summary Row in PF or PFE.

You would have to write a custom exporter.  You can report it as an enhancment ticket request on GitHub.

See the TextExporter example on the PF showcase: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml

Comment: Geez. It's a shame. Primefaces had save me a lot of code. Thank you anyway.